# Default Profile Image after delete current profile image in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image-upload

I have a photo upload script. In general everything is similar to general concepts. Also it is similar to Facebook's profile image logic. Differently I set user's profile picture by latest uploaded image. More clearly;

Steps:

1. user uploads profile picture
2. he/she can see the picture in some criteria comes from Mysql : `ORDER BY add_date DESC` so newest picture can fetched by php
3. Also I have a delete image button. If I use Mysql's `DELETE` keyword because of `ORDER BY DESC` newest picture is changing.
4. How can I set default picture after I click delete image button

---

[image]

as you can see from picture user 5 has added 3 different images in three different time. 
mysql query is : `SELECT path FROM profile_image WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['SES_USER_ID']." ORDER BY add_date DESC;"` showing picture to user and for fetching. earliest date is user's active profile image. (June 28 )

if I delete June 28, June 27's photo will be active profile image, not the default profile image.

How can I set default image?

Comment: why would you keep old images if you are not using them?

Comment: I will use old images in profile image album. Like facebook. So old images must stored in db

Comment: Why not just have an is_profile_pic column? If non are set to true - then use default?

Comment: @PLB you are right but not completely. User can have more than 1 profile picture. If user delete one of them, default profile picture(some example no_image.png) must shown to user, not 1 step older image comes from db

Comment: So, you ALWAYS want the LATEST active image to be the profile image?

Comment: Yes, and i solve the problem with adding new column, called is_active and default it's values is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have another table with fields userid, isset - ( with default value of 1 for all users)**

If user clicks the remove profile pic( wishes to have the default pic) , **change the value in isset to 0 for the respective user.**

**Check this table everytime before fetching the latest image from the profile pics table.**

*Alternatively you can have the isset field in the profile pics table itself. This would require you to change the isset value of every occurrence of the user's profile pic if he wishes to have the default pic.*

Comment: it is not completely solution but very close to my logic.